# Unable to interact with view in iOS 11 SearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I am unable to touch the view or scroll the tableview on `didpresentSearchcontroller` or `willpresentSearchcontroller` method of iOS 11 `SearchController` as shown in screenshot. There is some kind of dimming or `UISearchView` which not allowing me to touch the view controller or scroll the tableview. I think it disables the view. 
[image]

The greycolor view is not letting me touch the viewcontroller or tableview.

[image]

How can i interact with viewcontroller or scroll the tableview.

I want to show result on this view controller only .

```
// I dont want to show anotherview controller as result
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Comment: From your UI look and feel I think you are showing a transparent black layer.... which might be preventing the interaction with your views/controls.

Comment: It is by default showing in ios11 Searchcontroller when u add in navigationbar.

Comment: Are u using view controller or table view controller? Use search bar instead of search controller if you want to have interaction with under lying controls

Comment: Set `self.definesPresentationContext = true`  in your `viewController`

Comment: @Torongo this is not working. I have posted the answer bellow

Comment: You can set `self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true` after initialise the UISearchController. No need to do this on it's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. 
Use

```
let searchController = UISearchcontroller()
func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


}
```

Comment: You can set that property once when you create the instance of your search controller, probably in `viewDidLoad`. It's not necessary to do it every time you present it.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 12 it is:

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

You should add it before the refresh search.